# ESP32 USB Port Misadventure

Tags: power-supply, grounding, esp32

[image]I just had an incident where my laptop had two unresponsive ports and I am trying to figure out if it was my fault or a buggy driver.
Long story short I built a digital power meter for a linear PSU that I also built using an ESP32. I wanted to program the ESP, it crashed because I did not expect the code to compile that fast and did not press the buttons in time. After that I realized that 2/3 USB ports were not working anymore. To cut another long story short, I updated my laptop's Windows version to 11 (suspected driver issues with 10) and also updated the USB drivers for the hub.

The linear PSU was unplugged from AC power. The ESP32 was unplugged from its power supply. The linear PSU had no load connected to it. My laptop was plugged in.

So, was it my fault or was it a driver error? This panicked me and I thought about buying one of those USB isolators, despite the fact that they have slow data speeds and can only supply 200 mA of current.

*Later Edit the ports are all working fine now.

- 2nd Edit, added the schematic.
  Thank you for taking your time to read this.

Comment: Well, we don't know what happened and what do your schematics look like. But if your USB ports were damaged, likely something is wrong. If they were offline until shutting down the PC, it might have been an overcurrent protection that latched, or polyfuse that reset, or some latchup condition. Please provide schematics, and the USB isolators are effective only before you burn your laptop ports.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough in my text, the usb ports are working now. I forgot to mention this. The ports had power on them, just no data. Tested with two different usb mice and a flash drive. I will come back with schematic.